# Debugging needed in C program character array

Tags: c

Hey i needed to convert a c++ code in c.
The code is compiling without any error but is not giving any output.
Please can anyone point-out the mistake.
The same logic is giving the right output in cpp code please help me debug it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int flag = 0;
int min(int a, int b)
{
    return (a > b) ? b : a;
}
char *substr(const char *src, int m, int n)
{
    // get the length of the destination string
    int len = n - m;

    // allocate (len + 1) chars for destination (+1 for extra null character)
    char *dest = (char *)malloc(len + 1);

    // extracts characters between m'th and n'th index from source string
    // and copy them into the destination string
    for (int i = m; i < n && (*(src + i) != '\0'); i++)
    {
        *dest = *(src + i);
        dest++;
    }

    // null-terminate the destination string
    *dest = '\0';

    // return the destination string
    return dest - len;
}
char *substring(char *destination, const char *source, int beg, int n)
{

    while (n > 0)
    {
        *destination = *(source + beg);

        destination++;
        source++;
        n--;
    }

    *destination = '\0';

    return destination;
}
int compare(char *str1, int pos1, int n1, char *str2, int pos2, int n2)
{
    char substr1[50];
    substring(substr1, str1, pos1, n1);
    char substr2[50];
    substring(substr2, str2, pos2, n2);
    int res = strcmpi(substr1, substr2);
    return res;
}

int calcOverlappingPair(char s1[], char s2[], char str[])
{
    int max = INT_MIN;
    int m = strlen(s1);
    int n = strlen(s2);

    for (int i = 1; i <= min(m, n); i++)
    {

        if (compare(s1, m - i, i, s2, 0, i) == 0)
        {
            if (max < i)
            {

                max = i;
                char subs2[50];
                strcpy(subs2, substr(s2, i, strlen(s2)));
                strcpy(str, strcat(s1, subs2));
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= min(m, n); i++)
    {

        if (compare(s1, 0, i, s2, n - i, i) == 0)
        {
            if (max < i)
            {

                max = i;
                char subs1[50];
                strcpy(subs1, substr(s1, i, strlen(s1)));
                strcpy(str, strcat(s2, subs1));
            }
        }
    }

    return max;
}

void calculateShortestSuperstring(char arr[100][50], int n, char ans[50]) // no const, no-ref
{

    char temp[100][50];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        strcpy(temp[i], arr[i]);
    }
    char result[100][50];

    int maxArray[n - 1];
    int m = 0;

    int indexes[n];
    int k = 0;

    while (n != 1)
    {
        int max = INT_MIN;

        int p, q;

        char res_str[50];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {

            for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
            {
                char str[50];
                int r = calcOverlappingPair(arr[i], arr[j], str);

                if (max < r)
                {
                    max = r;
                    strcpy(res_str, str);
                    p = i;
                    q = j;
                }
            }
        }

        maxArray[m] = max;
        m++;

        flag = 1;

        indexes[k] = p;
        indexes[k + 1] = q;
        k = k + 2;

        n--;

        if (max == INT_MIN)
        {
            // arr[0] += arr[n];
            strcat(arr[0], arr[n]);
        }
        else
        {
            strcpy(arr[p], res_str);

            strcpy(arr[q], arr[n]);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(indexes) / sizeof(indexes[0]); i++)
    {
        int count = maxArray[i];
        int spaceCount = strlen(temp[indexes[i]]) - count;
        for (int k = 0; k < spaceCount; k++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf("%s \n", temp[indexes[i]]);
    }

    strcpy(ans, arr[0]);
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    int i;
    printf("Please enter number of lines (not more than 100)\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    while (n > 100)
    {

        printf("input lines cannot be greater than 100 . Please re-enter\n");
        scanf("%d", &n);
    }
    printf("Please enter the strings one per line \n");
    char input[100][50];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%s", input[i]);
    }

    char scs[50];
    calculateShortestSuperstring(input, n, scs);

    printf("The Shortest Superstring is %s \n", scs);
    printf("Length is : %d \n", strlen(scs));
    return 0;
}
```

*Input for this program is*

**4
1001001
100102
0010010
110010**
*and output should be*
**The Shortest Superstring is 1100100102**

Comment: What have you learned with your debugger?

Comment: i don't know how to use debugger i just code and try to check each part of code is working or not i think the way i handled string in c is not right. Please can you help me out

Comment: sounds like now is a great time to learn how to use a debugger. I used to be the same way, went thru years of school using only `printf` debugging bc I thought the learning curve for `gdb` would be too high. One day I finally decided to go for it. Within 10 min I was setting breakpoints, examining variables, memory, etc. Waiting so long is still one of my biggest regrets, I wasted a lot of time trying to find problems that would've gone much quicker with `gdb`. Highly recommend learning how to use a debugger, it will be well worth your time.

Comment: `compare` passes uninitialized pointers to `substring` as `destination` then those values are written to. That's undefined behavior.

Comment: ohk that helped but now the answer is way off the actual one can you help me figure out some other mistakes as well please.

Comment: `sizeof (char)` is defined as `1`, and there is  no need to cast the return of `malloc()` in C. `char *dest = malloc(len + 1);` is sufficient.

Comment: [enable and fix your warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/WEMG44T6n), would've seen the uninitialized values being used.

Comment: This doesn't even build, the `strcmpi` function isn't defined. You either haven't posted the code you're running with or you're running with a stale executable.

Answer (score 1):

valgrind says

```
==1850== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==1850==    at 0x10934A: substring(char*, char const*, int, int) (sh.cpp:37)
==1850==    by 0x1093A0: compare(char*, int, int, char*, int, int) (sh.cpp:51)
==1850==    by 0x109462: calcOverlappingPair(char*, char*, char*) (sh.cpp:66)
==1850==    by 0x109907: calculateShortestSuperstring(char (*) [50], int, char*) (sh.cpp:128)
==1850==    by 0x109D4F: main (sh.cpp:197)
==1850==
==1850== Invalid write of size 1
==1850==    at 0x10934A: substring(char*, char const*, int, int) (sh.cpp:37)
==1850==    by 0x1093A0: compare(char*, int, int, char*, int, int) (sh.cpp:51)
==1850==    by 0x109462: calcOverlappingPair(char*, char*, char*) (sh.cpp:66)
==1850==    by 0x109907: calculateShortestSuperstring(char (*) [50], int, char*) (sh.cpp:128)
==1850==    by 0x109D4F: main (sh.cpp:197)
==1850==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==1850==
==1850==
==1850== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==1850==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==1850==    at 0x10934A: substring(char*, char const*, int, int) (sh.cpp:37)
==1850==    by 0x1093A0: compare(char*, int, int, char*, int, int) (sh.cpp:51)
==1850==    by 0x109462: calcOverlappingPair(char*, char*, char*) (sh.cpp:66)
==1850==    by 0x109907: calculateShortestSuperstring(char (*) [50], int, char*) (sh.cpp:128)
==1850==    by 0x109D4F: main (sh.cpp:197)
```

the cause is this

```
char *substring(char *destination, const char *source, int beg, int n)
{

    while (n > 0)
    {
        *destination = *(source + beg);
```

is called from here

```
   int compare(char *str1, int pos1, int n1, char *str2, int pos2, int n2)
   {
       char *substr1; <<<<====== not inialized
       substring(substr1, str1, pos1, n1);
```

so you are derefencing a non initialized pointer - all bets off after that.

What is supposed to be there instead I do not know

Learn to use your debugger, takes 10 minutes

---

I gave valgrind your new code

```
==1862== Source and destination overlap in strcpy(0x1ffeffea22, 0x1ffeffea22)
==1862==    at 0x483F150: strcpy (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1862==    by 0x109B29: calculateShortestSuperstring(char (*) [50], int, char*) (sh.cpp:161)
==1862==    by 0x109D90: main (sh.cpp:198)
==1862==
       1001001
      0010010
  1001001
==1862== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1862==    at 0x109BDA: calculateShortestSuperstring(char (*) [50], int, char*) (sh.cpp:169)
==1862==    by 0x109D90: main (sh.cpp:198)
==1862==
```

Comment: I have edited that part its working but giving wrong ouput can you help in finding any more mistakes please.

Comment: @RanveerRaj if you are on linux run it under valgrind like I did, but mainly, learn to use your debugger,

Comment: can you change the code and post it please

Comment: @RanveerRaj have not changed any code, i took your edited code thats all